# How do I customise the auto-generated index.html in appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, mobile-website, html5-appcache

I am building a mobile app/mobile web solution in Appcelerator.  I want the mobileweb to be capabable of going offline.

I am not using Alloy.

I want to be able to add the appcache statement to the index.html, I also want to be able to make other customisations to this document.

I am aware that I can make the changes after its automatically generated but these would be overwritten the next time I create the file.

Is there anyway to define elements that I want inserted into the index.html as it is auto-generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to customize the `index.html` template is to do it in the Titanium SDK. This means you changes would affect all Mobile Web apps you build.

We wanted to allow you to customize the Mobile Web templates, but we never got around to actually doing it. :(

So, I recommend locating the installed Titanium SDK and copying it to something like `5.2.1.GA-MyApp`, then customize the templates in `mobileweb/src` to meet your needs.

Yes, I know this is gross, but it's about the best workaround today.

Comment: "We wanted to allow you to customize the Mobile Web templates, but we never got around to actually doing it. :("

As a product manager I find the phraseology here a little concerning.  The way this is written makes me think that you have finished developing further for mobile web and that as you did not get round to doing the work you never will.

Please put my mind at rest

Comment: Mobile Web is still "supported", but it hasn't been actively developed in 4 years. The team was pulled off of Mobile Web before we had a chance to work on themes, offline support, modules, performance, more parity, benchmarks, etc. There are currently 222 reported bugs and another 64 tickets for improvements and new features. I hope we get a chance to revisit it again. Many new ideas since virtual dom, weakmaps, service workers, etc have become available.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your candid response.